# Java number regex works but does not match?

Tags: java, regex

I'm in the middle of writing a regular expression to match any numeric values which i'm reading from an esri ascii file. Typically these values begin with an whitespace on each line (which has to be excluded), followed by other values each separated with a whitespace.

I've come up with following regex which matches and works in [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3crll) but somehow it doesn't seem to match any of the lines in my program.

Sample input from esri file looks like this:

```
" -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -340.86"
" -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -32768 -591.87"
```

Regex being used to catch these values is: `[^\s]-*\d.*`

I would be very grateful if you guys can help me out on this one!

Code:

```
//Pattern to match the headers of the esri file
Pattern header = Pattern.compile( "^(\\w+)\\s+(-?\\d+(.\\d+)?)");

BufferedReader input = null;
try 
{
    input = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( filename ) );

    while( input.ready() )
    {
        String line = input.readLine();
        Matcher headMatch = header.matcher( line );

        //Match all the heads
        if( headMatch.matches() ) {...}

        else if( line.matches( "[^\\s]-*\\d.*" ))
        {
           //process data, but this gets skipped..
           String[] inData = line.split("\\s+");
           ...
        }
     }
     ...
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Then post the code where it doesn't work. Try to make a [mcve].

Comment: this is the line of code: else if( line.matches( "[^\\s]-*\\d.*" ))

Comment: The `.*` is greedy, meaning it will consume everything it can. I don't think that is what you want... What exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: it should return all values in every line without the preceding whitespace.

Comment: Like this? http://regexr.com/3crlr

Comment: Hey Cricket, so I should get the whole line of values only without the preceding whitespace, when the regex returns such a line for me, I break this down further with a line.split(\\s+).

Comment: If there is nothing other than the numbers, why not just use `String.split`?

Comment: But you don't need to spilt if you can directly match all the numbers with a regex

Comment: The reason why I can't match every number directly is that each line and column represents a different coordinate in the axis (you should see the esri file as a grid).

Comment: [^\\s] means not a whitespace character. Did you want ^[\\s]? Otherwise it seems like all of your lines start with a space and couldn't match.

Comment: Hey @matt, so each line begins with a whitespace the regex should eliminate the first whitespace if possible.

Comment: .matches() doesn't do that. It only checks if it matches. I am posting an answer.

Comment: [^\\s] would be ignoring the first whitespace on each line or not?

Comment: [^\\s] says not a whitespace character. It has nothing to do with being on the first line. I will update my answer to include a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears he wants a line that matches and then has the whitespace removed.

```
if(line.matches("^\\s+[\\s-. \\d]*")){
    String[] inData = line.trim().split("\\s+");
}
```

That would try to match the line, then remove the excess whitespace before splitting.

String.matches, returns true if the regex matches the whole string. A regex like this would match anything that doesn't start with a whitespace.

```
"[^\\s].*"

"this".matches("[^\\s].*");  //true
" that".matches("[^\\s].*");  //false
```

The whole string has to match the regex and it doesn't modify the string. If I wanted something that removes the whitespace I have to use a Matcher so that I can get the groups that were found. eg. match the line, then take only the group with numbers. It is easier to just call String.trim()

Comment: You sir, are a savior! Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
^( *-?\d(\.?\d+)? *)*$
```

This is the minus sign once or none at all, followed by a number formed by at least 1 digit.

Also, if you have `double` values, it will catch the first set of digits before the dot and then check if there is at least 1 digit after the dot in the number.

Get a line where you have a number of white spaces, number, white spaces, no matter how many times.

Comment: Same thing I posted in the comments, but it doesn't seem that's what OP wants

Comment: I just checked you comment, I doubt it's the same. He needs even for double numbers, yours will fail for `-3.4`.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Your solution targets individual values though and I would prefer a solution where the entire line get's matched.

Comment: What do you mean? From `-3.4 34 -42` you want `-3.434-42` with no space, or what? Give us an example of what you expect.

Comment: It was the same before your edits :) and true, but the first link didn't contain any decimals.

Comment: Oh, then it's my bad :). I saw just 3-4 numbers, saw he needed just the numbers and gave it a try.

Comment: Expected result should be the complete line without the leading whitespace

Comment: @dotNes if you use line.matches you will not get the line back w/out the whitespace. Matches just checks if it matches. It doesn't change anything. Otherwise you have to use a Matcher and group.

Comment: @SimplyMe, I don't get any match in RegExr with this.